# How to configure apache2 in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: server, firefox, apache2, php, perl

I installed apache using ubuntu software center, and now it shows the following text on the page upon entrance of localhost in the addressbar of Firefox

**It works!**

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

Now I wanted firstly to run perl and php websites for testing in the apache localhost.
Can someone guide me in the process.

Answer (score 1):

http://tuxtweaks.com/2009/07/how-to-configure-apache-linux/

Why didn't you ask google, there are lots of tutorials :)

Comment: Can I install WAMP on Ubuntu

Comment: There is a similar program called XAMPP

Comment: Why WAMP cannot be installed? But it runs fine on Windows 7

Comment: instead of XAMPP, i am getting results of LAMP installation if I search for installation procedures of WAMP on the Ubuntu platform, why is that, Is there any problem,with WAMP on Ubuntu?

Comment: @ShadabK http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP - one of the components giving name to WAMP is Windows. I guess you cannot install Windows in Ubuntu, at least not in the way intended in the WAMP stack idea. LAMP is Linux + Apache + MySQL + PHP (or Python or Perl). WAMP is almost the same, just with Windows.

Comment: @Babajaga  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.